# How To Display HTML Entities (decimal) In PHP?

Tags: php, html, html-entities

How do i display the percent sign `%` in PHP using unicode `&#037;`?

Here is the code.

```
echo $percent . "&#037;";
```

I have the code inside a PHP function on a separate page it is then displayed on the HTML page.

Comment: Could you clarify the problem? What happens when you use the code you posted?

Comment: As indicated by alex, the code you've supplied will do precisely what you ask. Although in most cases, displaying a percent sign in HTML (via PHP or otherwise) is no more complicated than simply echoing out a percent sign '%'. So its possible you've not given enough information to really answer your question.

Comment: The php code just displays `99&#037;` for example.

Comment: Is there any reason why you don't just do `echo $percent . "%";`

Comment: Using the entity is better then using just the percent sign %

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean how to display it in HTML once echo()'d from PHP? Your code there should do it. I just tested it on [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/ifaqu) (the HTML entity at least).

Judging by your comment,

> The php code just displays 99 &#037;
>   for example.

Well, it should, of course, in the HTML. If your viewing that in the front of your browser, it would be likely your encoding `htmlspecialchars()` or similar. But since you are echo'ing, that should be hard to capture and encode, unless using output buffer functions. Can you provide any more information please?

Comment: I want for example `99%` to be displayed. sorry for the confusion.

Comment: I have the code inside a PHP function on a separate page it is then displayed on the HTML page.

Answer (score 1):

have you looked at the html source that's being output? does it say

```
99&#037;
```

or

```
99&amp;#037;
```

or something similar?

Why are you using the entity? There's nothing wrong with

```
echo $percent . '%';
```

Comment: Using the entity is better then using just the percent sign %

Comment: @OpenID What is your reasoning behind this?

Answer (score 0):

```
$var = $percent . "&#037;";
echo str_replace('&#037;', '%', $var); // POG :O
```

Comment: This would be easier but I really want to use unicode`echo $percent . "%";`, Whats the ups in using your version of the code?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following: `sprintf("99%%.  Hopefull will echo out a percent sign!",$str,$number);`

[link text](http://www.w3schools.com/PHP/func_string_sprintf.asp)

Let me know if that works?